# The first read/copy/write to my dll file takes 600ms

Tags: python, windows, dll, disk, antivirus

I have a DLL I built called test.dll (~3MB). As part of my build process, I copy the DLL to another location as soon as it's created. The following Python code is not actually my build process, but is a simplified case that still exhibits the slow behaviour:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["copy", "/Y", "test.dll", "test2.dll"], shell=True)
subprocess.run(["copy", "/Y", "test2.dll", "test3.dll"], shell=True)
```

The first copy is fast (2-15ms). The second copy is extremely slow (600ms+). What is causing this? I'm even on an SSD, I would expect copying such a small file to be pretty fast.

I'm using subprocess.run() in order to remove Python from the equation. It looks like this is a latency built into Windows in some way. I see similar results with shutil.copy(), and using other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Defender (or another antivirus program) is scanning the newly-created DLL after the first copy operation completes. This scan can take some time (~600ms in this case). It seems to only happen for filetypes Defender sees as high-risk, like EXE and DLL, but probably also some others. Defender seems to check the first few bytes of the file to figure out its type, instead of using the file extension (because the extension could of course trivially be changed to hide an EXE/DLL).

Disable Windows Defender and try running again to see if the times have improved. If they have, re-enable Defender and add an exception for your build directory, compiler and linker, etc. Run again, and confirm the time is still improved.

As a bonus, not only will this improve your copy time, but your build time will probably also drop by a similar 600ms per output file.

**PSA**: Without me realizing, this latency has existed on every single write operation to a new EXE or DLL in almost my entire programming career (at least since Windows Defender has come included with the OS). 600ms may not seem like a lot, but it's huge when compounded over every single build I've even done, and then multiplied further for builds with multiple targets, file copies, and so on. This is an enormous amount of time spent waiting for Defender to scan the EXE/DLL I myself just created.

Comment: Some  don't like people answering their own questions it seems!